# Regex to match a string within quotation marks that contains the word "detail"

Tags: regex

I want to grab all words within quotation marks that contains the word detail

> > e.g. If the String is lore ispim sfs:lk-"fkjslk-detail-sdfsd" something

Then I want to match `fkjslk-detail-sdfsd`

So far I have this but I suspect I am not on track

```
""([^"]*)"\"detail\":\"([^\"]*)\""
```

Comment: What about a string like `foo "bar" detail "baz" bam`? `detail` is found between quotes, but do you still want to match it?

Comment: Good question Tim, no wouldn't want to match it in that case.

Comment: Although that doesn't happen in my text, so can ignore that problem.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. I need to learn regex, having different options will help to see the differences and see what differences each option provides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lazy` regex with a positive lookahead:

*update #1 improved regex*

```
"([^"]*(?=detail).*?)"
```

[Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/hJ4zH9)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this regex.

```
(?="[^"]*detail[^"]*")("[^"]+")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
"(.*?detail.*?)"
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a simple regex:

```
".*?\bdetail\b.*?"
```